# Removing individual page from map series

Tags: arcgis-pro, map-series

I'm trying to delete/remove a single page from a map series I created in ArcGIS Pro.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to apply a definition query to the index layer of your map series which excludes the feature that generates the page you do not want.

Another would be to delete that feature entirely.